# Creating tuples using a variable number of for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, variables, tuples, python-2.x

Given `n` and `k`, I need to create all tuples of length `k` whose entries are from `range(n)` (0 to n-1) such that the tuple's entries are in dictionary order and there are parentheses in a particular format. Specifically, the tuple has parentheses around each pair, from inside out.

For example, if `n=3` and `k=4`, then I would like the output to include something like `(((0,0),1),2)`, but **not** something like `(((0,0),2),1)`.

The code below works for this specific instance. The issue is that I don't know how to generalize on `k`, which is the *number of `for` loops* in the code below. I can only do this for a specific `k`, like `k=4` here. I really need to be able to do this for **any** value of `k`.

```
n=3
k=4
my_list = []
for a in range(n):
    x = a
    for b in range(a,n):
        y = (x,b)
        for c in range(b,n):
            z = (y,c)
            for d in range(c,n):
                w = (z,d)
                my_list.append(w)
print my_list
```

Output:

`[(((0, 0), 0), 0), (((0, 0), 0), 1), (((0, 0), 0), 2), (((0, 0), 1), 1), (((0, 0), 1), 2), (((0, 0), 2), 2), (((0, 1), 1), 1), (((0, 1), 1), 2), (((0, 1), 2), 2), (((0, 2), 2), 2), (((1, 1), 1), 1), (((1, 1), 1), 2), (((1, 1), 2), 2), (((1, 2), 2), 2), (((2, 2), 2), 2)]`

Comment: where does `k` come into this? is it the number of `for` loops?

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @user1558604: Yes, k is the number of for loops.

Comment: I have no clue if its the best way to model this "algorithm" but if you want to vary the number of loops you could convert it into a recursive function that recurses k times...as long as k doesn't get too big and hit the maximum recursion limit

Comment: @RaySteam: I am using Sage to work with some graph structures, specifically taking a graph G and multiplying by itself (Cartesian product) k times. In the resulting graph, its vertices are of the form indicated in my post, with the parentheses that way. I am trying to figure out how to remove "redundant" vertices from that product graph.

Comment: @BlueLightning42: I definitely thought about recursion, but I don't know how to actually make that *happen* in this case.

Comment: So you have a graph in Python and want to remove "redudant" vertices? So for instance `(((0,0),1),2)` is equal to `(((0,0),2),1)`?

Comment: @RaySteam Yes, precisely.

Comment: An your idea is generate the valid ones and filter by those? Why don't just remove duplicates?

Comment: @RaySteam: Yes, that was my idea. If you have a better one, go for it!

Comment: Just one more question what do you mean by dictionary order?

Comment: @RaySteam: Lexicographic. Just like you pointed out: 0012 is in order, but 0021 is not so I'd want it removed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, I hope it is relevant:

```
n=4
k=4
my_list=[(((a,b),c),d) for a in range(n) for b in range(a,n) for c in range(b,n) for d in range(c,n) ]
print my_list
```

**Output**:

> [(((0, 0), 0), 0), (((0, 0), 0), 1), (((0, 0), 0), 2), (((0, 0), 0),
>   3), (((0, 0), 1), 1), (((0, 0), 1), 2), (((0, 0), 1), 3), (((0, 0),
>   2), 2), (((0, 0), 2), 3), (((0, 0), 3), 3), (((0, 1), 1), 1), (((0,
>   1), 1), 2), (((0, 1), 1), 3), (((0, 1), 2), 2), (((0, 1), 2), 3),
>   (((0, 1), 3), 3), (((0, 2), 2), 2), (((0, 2), 2), 3), (((0, 2), 3),
>   3), (((0, 3), 3), 3), (((1, 1), 1), 1), (((1, 1), 1), 2), (((1, 1),
>   1), 3), (((1, 1), 2), 2), (((1, 1), 2), 3), (((1, 1), 3), 3), (((1,
>   2), 2), 2), (((1, 2), 2), 3), (((1, 2), 3), 3), (((1, 3), 3), 3),
>   (((2, 2), 2), 2), (((2, 2), 2), 3), (((2, 2), 3), 3), (((2, 3), 3),
>   3), (((3, 3), 3), 3)]

Comment: This only works for fixed `k`; the request for something that works for *any* `k`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work.

```
def tuples(n, k):
    if k == 2:
        return [(i,j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i, n)]
    else:
        return [(t, m) for t in tuples(n, k-1) for m in range(t[1], n)]
```

The base case generates precisely the tuples you need in the result.

From each tuple `(x,y)` produced by the recursive case, we create a set of tuples `((x, y), z)` with `z >= y`.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, based on `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`:

```
import itertools

n, k = 4, 4
f = lambda x: (f(x[:-1]), x[-1]) if len(x)>2 else x

print(*map(f, itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(n), k)), sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
(((0, 0), 0), 0)
(((0, 0), 0), 1)
(((0, 0), 0), 2)
(((0, 0), 0), 3)
(((0, 0), 1), 1)
...and so on.
```

Comment: Nice, although you should change f by a proper function definition.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the itertools builtin library? https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations_with_replacement

At first glance at your issue, It looks like you're essentially creating a list of all combinations with replacement (although, you would really want to use k+1). This would not have the "nested" property, but it would give you exactly the numbers you want, and I imagine adjusting the structure would be much easier than coming up with the recursive algorithm you would need to do it your way. Here's an example:

```
import itertools

n = 3
k = 4
choices = range(n)
output = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(choices, k + 1)
# output = [(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), ...]
```

Comment: I have seen that. It's really the nested parentheses that are the problem.