# ITEM is variable in python FOR loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to work out a more efficient way to write the below in python.  In effect I want to automatically create a list that will contain all the possible combinations of another list.

So for my example below, would create a.a.a, a.a.b, a.a.c ..... c.c.c

What I want to do though is make the size of the combination list larger, ie go up to a,b,c & d.  This currently involves adding in another FOR statement in the below to be able to run through this 4th combination.

Is there anyway to make the Item listing of the FOR statements also variable based on the number of items in the combination list (similar to how I have made the expression list variable as well)?

(I have had a look at [Creating tuples using a variable number of for loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59200990/creating-tuples-using-a-variable-number-of-for-loops) but could not work out if we are attempting to do the same thing, and my other searches only find questions on how to make the iterable variable)

```
word_ls=['A','B','C']
num_word =[]
loop_len =len(word_ls)


#create the expression which will be used to generate the word listing, which will then be used to match up to the log/ lat co-ordinates
expression=''
for create_string in range(loop_len):    # this replaces >  num_word.append(word_ls[item1] + '.' + word_ls[item2] + '.' + word_ls[item3])

    expression = expression + "word_ls[item{0}".format(create_string+1)+ "] + '.' + "

expression = expression.strip(" + '.' +")

for item1 in range(loop_len):
    for item2 in range(loop_len):    
        for item3 in range(loop_len):
                num_word.append(eval(expression))
```

Comment: Take a look at the python itertools module

Comment: thanks for the pointer and also the responses below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement

e.g.

```py
import itertools
items = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(items, len(items)))
```

or possibly product as @andrepd suggests above.

```
list(itertools.product(items, repeat=len(items)))
```

It depends whether you would want things like CBA in the output, or only the strictly ordered ABC.

Comment: This isn't quite the same as the OP's loop structure suggests, as it would treat permutations of the same triple as equivalent and only yield one of them.

Answer (score 1):

This is `itertools.product()`.

```
import itertools

print(itertools.product('abc', repeat=3))
```

will yield aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, ..., ccb, ccc.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it yields `('a', 'a', 'a')`, `('a', 'a', 'b')`, etc.